# How to display Arabic names properly in QGIS 3.34?

Tags: qgis, openstreetmap, qgis-plugins

I'm new to QGIS, I've downloaded some places names from QuickOSM plugin and everything was working fine. Also I have my encoding set as it should be. However, the text is not displaying correctly! It is going left to right instead of right to left! In other words the text is reversed, like if you are typing *England* as *dnalgnE*. Please check the picture below.

[image: sample]

So how to correct that? I tried to change the encoding but its grayed out and the text inside the `Attribute Table` is correct, any idea how to fix that?

Comment: This is a known issue that was already reported (by yours truly), feel free to add your input in that GitHub issues page
https://github.com/qgis/QGIS/issues/54098

Comment: @MrXsquared its going left to right instead of right to left! in other words the text is reversed.. like u r typing England -> dnalgnE